# Handling MubLazor dialog closure from a parent component

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor-webassembly, mudblazor

I'm working on a project using `MudBlazor`, and I'm encountering an issue with managing the closure of a dialog. In my `Countries` page, there's a button that, when clicked, opens a dialog using MudBlazor. Below is the code snippet from my Countries page:

```
<ActionHeader Title="@Localizer["Countries"]" CreateButton="true" OnCreateButtonClick="OnCreate"  />
// Code to open the dialog in the Countries page
private async void OnCreate()
{
    // ... (Code to initialize the model and open the dialog)
    var dialog = DialogService.Show<CountriesFormDialog>("Create a new Country", parameters, options);

    var dialogResult = await dialog.Result;
    if (!dialogResult.Canceled)
    {
        // ... (Code to handle the dialog result)
        await _service.CreateAsync(dto) // I do not want to close the dialog till I do not have the response from the server.
        OnRefresh();
    }
}
```

The dialog is implemented in a component called `CountriesFormDialog`:

```
<MudDialog >
    <DialogContent >
        <CountriesForm @ref="@_countryForm" Model="Model" OnFormSubmit="OnFormSubmitHandler"></CountriesForm>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">@Localizer["Cancel"]</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Class="btn btn-primary">@Localizer["Ok"]</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
```

And the corresponding `CountriesFormDialog` code-behind:

```
// Code for CountriesFormDialog
public partial class CountriesFormDialog
{
    [CascadingParameter] private MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public CountryDTO Model { get; set; } = default!;

    private CountriesForm? _countryForm;

    protected async Task Submit()
    {
        await _countryForm!.Submit();
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        MudDialog.Cancel();
    }

    protected Task OnFormSubmitHandler(CountryDTO model)
    {
        MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(model));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The CountriesForm component is as follows:

```
<!-- Code for CountriesForm -->
<MudForm Model="@Model" @ref="@_form" Validation="@(_modelValidator.ValidateValue)">
    <!-- ... (Form fields and controls) -->
</MudForm>
```

Now, my challenge is to move the logic for closing the dialog from CountriesFormDialog to the main Countries component. I want to delay the closure of the dialog until I receive a response from the server because there might be errors that need to be displayed. I aim to allow the main Countries component to handle the dialog closure based on certain conditions. How can I modify my code to implement this delayed closure logic?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know this is not possible at the current time.

I can suggest two options.
First option, move the dialog in the main component, so you can have full control the dialog's visibility

```
<MudDialog @bind-IsVisible="isDialogVisible" Options="options">
    <DialogContent >
        <CountriesForm @ref="@_countryForm" Model="Model" OnFormSubmit="OnFormSubmitHandler"></CountriesForm>
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton OnClick="Cancel">@Localizer["Cancel"]</MudButton>
        <MudButton Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="Submit" Variant="Variant.Filled" Class="btn btn-primary">@Localizer["Ok"]</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>

<ActionHeader Title="@Localizer["Countries"]" CreateButton="true" OnCreateButtonClick="OnCreate"  />

@code {
    private bool isDialogVisible ;
    
    // Code to open the dialog in the Countries page
    private async void OnCreate()
    {
        isDialogVisible = true;
    }

    protected async Task Submit()
    {
        await _countryForm!.Submit();
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        isDialogVisible = false;
    }

    protected Task OnFormSubmitHandler(CountryDTO model)
    {
        await _service.CreateAsync(model)
        isDialogVisible = false;
        OnRefresh();
    }
}
```

Second option is to move the server call from the main component to the CountriesFormDialog and close the dialog only after you receive a response from the server

```
// Code for CountriesFormDialog
public partial class CountriesFormDialog
{
    [CascadingParameter] private MudDialogInstance MudDialog { get; set; } = default!;

    [Parameter] public CountryDTO Model { get; set; } = default!;

    private CountriesForm? _countryForm;

    protected async Task Submit()
    {
        await _countryForm!.Submit();
    }

    private void Cancel()
    {
        MudDialog.Cancel();
    }

    protected Task OnFormSubmitHandler(CountryDTO model)
    {
        await _service.CreateAsync(model)
        MudDialog.Close(DialogResult.Ok(true));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

I hope this could be useful for you.

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, for now I have implemented something similar to what you suggest